# Uncaught Syntax Error: Invalid regular expression : Invalid character class

Tags: email-validation, polymer-3.x

My Polymer.js code has the following input element (it is intended to accept email addresses that have an “@” symbol AND a domain eg. “.com”)

I have tried adding like this

but in chrome console I am getting this below error

Pattern attribute value ^[_A-Za-z0-9]+(.[_A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[_A-Za-z0-9]+(.[_A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/v: Invalid character class

What syntax do I have wrong?

Comment: <oe-input validate-on-input required label="l_emailid"
  pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$" value="{{emailId}}"> </oe-input> sorry added code is not visible in the question, so adding it as a comment